# Sending very big string data as parameter to applet from javascript

Tags: java, javascript, applet

Is there any restriction on sending very big string data as parameter to applet from javascript? Big I mean ~70mb text data.

Comment: As far as I know there is no such restriction. Are you getting some error?

Comment: What, you are seriously putting 70 Meg of data into an applet `param`?  Applet parameters are meant for things like a string representing the **file name** or **relative path** of the 70 Meg of data to load.  It would not surprise me in the slightest if it failed with 70 Meg of data (whether by design or by simply failing to test the browser for such extraordinary corner cases).

Comment: We have an proprietary applet which sign text with PKCS#7. We need to sing base64 of file binary. I guess unfortunately we have to rewrite this applet to send file path as parameter.